# Display text from date attribute and URL link with parameter

Tags: jquery

I have several links and DIV for displaying text.
I need to display the text in div (sometext) and redirect to url with the parameter ...?lok=n&prohl=n  after clicking on the link.

After redirecting, the text just flashes and disappears ...  I need the text to be visible after redirecting.
Thank you

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id = "container">
     <ul id = "someID">
         <li> <a data-text="some text 1" href="?lok=1&prohl=1"> A </a> </li>
         <li> <a data-text="some text 2" href="?lok=2&prohl=2"> B </a> </li>
         <li> <a data-text="some text 3" href="?lok=3&prohl=3"> C </a> </li>
     </ul>
</div>
<div id="sometext"> ...abc </div> 


$ ('#someID a').on('click', function (event) {
     var text = $(this).attr('data-text');
     var link = $(this).attr ('href');
     location.replace ("www.somedomain.xy" + link);
     $ ('#sometext').text(text);
});
```

Comment: the issue is because the current page is being unloaded and a new one is being loaded. As HTTP is stateless there is no direct data transfer between HTML pages, so you will need a method of doing this manually. I'd suggest researching cookies, localStorage, sessionStorage or AJAX requests.

Comment: It works!  via sessionStorage. Many thanks